# Use gdb with alsa-lib-1.1.3

Tags: c, linux, gdb, alsa

i am trying to use gdb with alsa-lib in the next code, i use gdb for see a pointer struct, but i find this `<incomplete type>` when use gdb

i use for compiler the gcc and i put a flag -lasound

```
 gcc ejemplo.c   -lasound  -g  -o ejemplo
```

+

```
    #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    //#include"pcm_local.h"
    //#include <sound/asound.h>

    int main()
    { 
      snd_pcm_t *handle_capture;
      snd_pcm_open(&handle_capture,"default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, SND_PCM_ASYNC);
       return 0;
    }
```

i put a break in line 15 (before return 0) and see this

```
(gdb) break 15
(gdb) p *handle_capture
<incomplete type>
```

i see pcm.h a declaration in line 327

```
typedef struct _snd_pcm snd_pcm_t
```

and search  _snd_pcm and i find of declaration in `"pcm_local.h"` line 179

```
 struct _snd_pcm {
```

i add the library but a appear errors  or double declaration.

also i see the  declarations of libasound.so

```
nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so
```

but i don't find the declaration (_snd_pcm or snd_pcm_t),
and see that i don't know it is possible  use gdb if in libasond.so don't appear  this declaration.

i read in other post that a problem is solve if add `#include <sound/asound.h>` but i find same error of double declaration, i think that i solve error of double declaration comment parts in library pcm_local.h of code but i don't know if it is a good solution, any  can help me, what do i  need to know for use gdb whith alsa?, i searched in google (Googlear) any solution but i don't find any solution.

Comment: i saw the function to see state of handle, the functions are in pcm.c, in pcm.c add  #include "pcm_local.h" in line 640 (i think that i need to add for use dereference pointers ), pcm.h have declarations of pcm.c how snd_pcm_name(), but if a want to use printf("%s\n",handle_capture->name)
appear the next error   
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘snd_pcm_t {aka struct _snd_pcm}’
 but i don't understand what happen   why not appear this error when use a function snd_pcm_name(handle_capture)?
const char *snd_pcm_name(snd_pcm_t *pcm)
{
 assert(pcm);
 return pcm->name;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program doesn't include `pcm_local.h`.  The pointer you're using is intended to be used as an *opaque pointer*.  The include file intended for use by applications has just a forward declaration.  Your application is supposed to treat it like a handle, analogous to `FILE *`.

You probably don't really want to know what it points to.  If you do, you'll have to make sure your alsa library is compiled with debugging information attached (not stripped), and you'll have to step into the alsa library function deep enough until you reach code that *does* include  `pcm_local.h`.

Yes, there are ways to include the structure definition and get gdb to dereference the pointer for you.  But that way lies madness.  Tricking a debugger into doing something is a good way to fake yourself out.

If what you're really interested in is some aspect of the state of the alsa handle, look for functions that report its state.

Comment: are the only ways to see information about handle ? use pcm.c functions, the (alsa-lib) is build with this propose, is it a correct ?
if i want use gdb with alsa,  is not a good idea?